# Flowdock: how to get mentions/notifications

Tags: api, flowdock

I am trying to build a bot for answering (only) my mentions and it seems I can't easily do that.

Is it possible to get something like application's own https://www.flowdock.com/rest/notifications/mentions call using the official REST API of Flowdock?

I couldn't find any easy way, just going through all my flows and searching for mentions via tags (tag being my username), which is pretty unoptimal and hard to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've handled this as follows via UNOFFICIAL APIs:

1. mentions via https://www.flowdock.com/rest/notifications/mentions?limit=%d
2. private messages via https://www.flowdock.com/rest/notifications/unreads